# Tracing a stack in x86 assembly code

Tags: x86, stack, trace, assembly

I'm looking at a practice exam for one of my classes and I just don't understand a few aspects of the problem, so maybe you help me (probably really easy if you know x86).

So it's problem 8 here:
http://www.coe.utah.edu/~cs4400/schedule/exam3.F10.pdf

And the solution to it is here: 
http://www.coe.utah.edu/~cs4400/schedule/exam3_solns.F10.pdf\

I just don't understand how the values are obtained in the solution. Let me run through how I intepret the stack:

```
08048510 <callfoo>:
08048510: 55       pushl %ebp               # old frame pointer is pushed to the stack  
08048511: 89 e5    movl %esp,%ebp           # frame pointer = stack pointer
08048513: 83 ec 08 subl $0x8,%esp           # allocates 8 bytes for stack
08048516: 83 c4 f4 addl $0xfffffff4,%esp    # this I believe allocates 4 bytes to the stack??
08048519: 68 9c 85 04 08 pushl $0x804859c   # push string address
0804851e: e8 d1 ff ff ff call 80484f4 <foo> # call foo, which takes the string address as param1
08048523: 89 ec    movl %ebp,%esp           # (after foo) does similar to return out of function
08048525: 5d       popl %ebp
08048526: c3       ret

080484f4 <foo>:
080484f4: 55       pushl %ebp                  # push old frame pointer
080484f5: 89 e5    movl %esp,%ebp              # frame pointer = stack pointer
080484f7: 83 ec 18 subl $0x18,%esp             # allocate 24 bytes 
080484fa: 8b 45 08 movl 0x8(%ebp),%eax         # moves the param1 (string pointer) into eax
080484fd: 83 c4 f8 addl $0xfffffff8,%esp       # allocates 8 more bytes (?)
08048500: 50       pushl %eax                  # push x # pushes param1 to stack
08048501: 8d 45 fc leal 0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax  # adds 12 to the frame pointer, puts it in eax(?)  
08048504: 50       pushl %eax                  # push buf (which apparently is located in eax and 0xc(%ebp)
08048505: e8 ba fe ff ff call 80483c4 <strcpy> # copies the string from param1 into buf
0804850a: 89 ec    movl %ebp,%esp              # puts stack pointer into ebp
0804850c: 5d       popl %ebp                   # pops ebp (returns back to other function)
0804850d: c3       ret
```

(a) So after doing that, I guess I can see kinda how buf[0] = `0x64636261`. A char is one byte, and being little endian, it could also be read like this: buf[0] = `0x61626364` (although I don't know if my prof would accept that answer). **However**, I don't understand how buf[2] is equal to `0x08040069` or `0x69000408`. It has the last character, then a null character, but what are the `04` and `08`?

(b) I'm not sure how to get (b) or (c). Where do I even obtain what the value of `esp` is to find out what is put into `ebp` at the beginning of `foo`? Overall I'm just confused on these last two... help? :(

Comment: Right, I got that connection, I just don't think I would assume the section of memory after buf would 100% contain the beginning of an address. And therefore I wouldn't put that on the test. (b) (c) are even more confusing as far as that goes, I just don't get where they are getting those addresses. :/

Comment: When foo gets called at 0804851e the next instruction (return address) is pushed into the stack (08048523). Foo allocates 8 bytes to the stack and then writes 10 bytes, thus partially overwriting the return address on the stack.

Comment: Ah, so this one is related to buffer overflow. However, for some reason I read it as allocating more than 10 bytes. Could you tell me where I'm wrong in my notes for the assembly? I have it allocating 24 bytes, then 8 more bytes, so a total of 32 bytes. Then does %eax = %ebp + 12, which I would assume is going to the wrong location, because wouldn't that be going outside the stack?

Comment: Line 08048516 comment is wrong: 

    addl $0xfffffff4,%esp  # this I believe allocates 4 bytes to the stack??

0 - 0xfffffff4 = 0x0C = 12 decimal bytes

, equivalent instruction: 

    subl $0xC,%esp

Comment: 08048501 is also wrong, should be -4

Comment: Am I the only getting: "You don't have permission to access /~cs4400/schedule/exam3.F10.pdf on this server."

Comment: It was a practice test for my class last year, unfortunately I think they may have taken it down.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a lot of unnecessary manipulation of the stack pointer going on in this code, but all that really matters is that the `buf` variable is at `ebp-4`. You can see that from the sequence:

```
leal 0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax 
pushl %eax
call 80483c4 <strcpy>
```

`0xfffffffc` is -4, so `leal 0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax` sets eax to the address of the memory location `ebp-4`. That value is then pushed onto the stack as the first argument to `strcpy`. Since the first argument passed to `strcpy` is `buf`, we know that the address of `buf` is at `ebp-4`.

Now consider how the stack builds up as `foo` is called.

First the string address is pushed by the instruction `pushl $0x804859c`.

```
0804859c   # string pointer
```

Then when the function `foo` is called, the address of the instruction following the call (`08048523`) is pushed onto the stack as the return address.

```
08048523   # return address
```

Then inside foo, ebp is saved on the stack. It could be anything at this point.

```
????????   # saved ebp
```

Then ebp is set to esp, so it's now pointing to the location where the previous ebp was saved.

Now because we know that `buf` is at ebp-4, that means the very next item on the stack will be `buf`. There is a lot more space allocated on the stack than is necessary by the `subl` and `addl` instructions, but all we care about is that `buf` is at `ebp-4`. So the part of the stack that we care about looks like this:

```
0804859c   # string pointer
08048523   # return address
????????   # saved ebp      <- ebp points here
????????   # buff[0]        <- ebp-4 points here
```

So now what happens when you copy "abcdefghi" into buff? Because the machine is little endian, those dwords are going to fill up from right to left. You have 9 characters plus a null terminator in that string, so you're going to overwrite all four bytes of `buff[0]`, all four bytes of the saved ebp, and then two bytes of the return address.

So your stack now looks like this:

```
0804859c   # string pointer
08040069   # return address
68676665   # saved ebp      <- ebp points here
64636261   # buff[0]        <- ebp-4 points here
```

From that, it should be fairly obvious what the answers to the various questions are.

Since the stack builds downward in memory, `buff[1]` and `buff[2]` are located immediately above `buff[0]` in the stack representation as I've shown it. So you can see the various buff values are just:

```
buff[0] = 0x64636261
buff[1] = 0x68676665
buff[2] = 0x08040069
```

Then Immediately before the `ret` instruction, we have the following two instructions:

```
movl %ebp,%esp
popl ebp
```

The first sets esp to the current value of ebp, so it will be pointing to the position on the stack where the previous ebp was saved. However, looking at the stack representation, you can see that that value has now been overwritten with `68676665`. So when you pop ebp, that's the value you're going to get.

```
%ebp = 0x68676665
```

Similarly, when the function returns, it's going to try and pop the return address off the stack, but again you can see from the stack representation that the original return address has been partially overwritten. So immediately after the `ret` instruction eip will have popped `08040069`.

```
$eip = 0x08040069
```

And that, I think, answers all your questions.

I realise this question is now several years old, but it hasn't been closed and there isn't an accepted answer, so perhaps this explanation might still be of some use to someone.

Comment: I was just browsing my old questions and WOW, you are a gentleman and a scholar.